# Исключение в selenium при работе модуля InstaPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instapy

При работе с модулем InstaPy вылетает исключение следующего рода

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: document.getElementByClassNmae(...)[0] is undefined

Суть ошибки понимаю, не понимаю как исправить. Где искать причину того что скрипт не может произвести селективную выборку по названию класса?

ps: До этого была ошибка связанная с разрядностью системы в `webdriverdownload.py`. Баг пофикшен [так](https://github.com/leonidessaguisagjr/webdriverdownloader/pull/12/commits).

pss: Мой код:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="myusername", password="mypassword", headless_browser=False)
session.like_by_tags(["world"], amount=5)
session.end()
```

Comment: Искать, наверное, нужно в вашем коде, который вы забыли привести в вопросе...

Comment: @strawdog прошу прощения, добавил!

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка выводится из кода,который ты не вписал,и она заключается в том ,что ты неверно указал значение,а такие условия указываются подобным образом:
document.getElementByClassName('значение класса в скобках').click()